# What is the most authentic Reformed 'ordo salutis'?

Tags: soteriology, reformed-theology

This question follows on from a comment made in the previous [closed question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83114/calvins-ordo-salutis-could-be-acrostic-with-tulip-however-what-could-be-the-bes).

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordo_salutis#:%7E:text=Ordo%20salutis%20has%20been%20defined,some%20elements%20are%20understood%20to) article on the subject of *ordo salutis* quotes  and lists the following, in the following order, as 'Calvinistic' :

> Predestination
> Election
> Calling
> Regeneration
> Faith
> Repentance
> Justification
> Adoption
> Sanctification
> Perseverance
> Glorification

This list is attributed by Wikipedia to   :

> "The 'Order of Salvation'" In Feinberg, John S. (ed.). The Cross and Salvation: The Doctrine of Salvation. Wheaton: Good News Publishers. pp. 36–44. ISBN 978-1-58134-812-5.

Would Reformed Calvinistic Baptists consider this to be the correct and definitive *ordo salutis* or is there another, or others, considered more authentic ?